# Kafka ProcessorContext offset out of order

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Kafka Streams and an implementation of a Transformer in order to get metadata such as partition and offset for each message. I add this information to a list and witness that at some point, the offset goes "back in time" (please note that I groupByKey so I would assume that offset is always increasing and that I verified that partition is 29 for every message):

```
    "offset": 441511,
    "offset": 441512,
    "offset": 441513,
    "offset": 441514,
    "offset": 441515,
    "offset": 441516,
    "offset": 441517,
    "offset": 441518,
    "offset": 50,
    "offset": 51,
    "offset": 52,
    "offset": 53,
```

The transformer is really simple:

```
public class OriginalSensorDataTransformer implements Transformer<
        String,
        OriginalSensorData,
        KeyValue<String, OriginalSensorData>> {

    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue transform(String key, OriginalSensorData value) {
        OriginalSensorData originalSensorData = new OriginalSensorData(
                value.getTimestamp(),
                value.getInstallationId(),
                value.getAssetId(),
                value.getData(),
                context.partition(),
                context.offset());

        return KeyValue.pair(key, originalSensorData);
    }
```

and the dsl I'm using:

```
 stream
                .transform(OriginalSensorDataTransformer::new)
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(....)
```

Reading the topic using the kafka console consumer does show that the offsets increase as expected. any idea what could cause this?

kafka version 2.0.1 and spring cloud stream kafka Greenwich.SR1

Comment: how many jvms/threads are you running this on? (basically - is there any parallelism?) does this coincide with consumer group rebalance? are you using auto offset commits?

Comment: I'm using a single jvm with auto commit and I did not notice any rebalancing. Also my consumer is a single one

Comment: are you using kafka transactions? i thinking either your consumer reverted backwards to committed offset (because crash/restart/rebalance) of those records belong to a transaction that was just then committed ?

Comment: If you use `aggregate()` by default the output is cached (LRU based). This may reorder downstream messages. If you want to preserve the order, you can disable caching via passing `Materialized.as(null).withCachingDisabled()` into `aggregate()` or disable caching globally by setting cache size to zero in `StreamsConfig`.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I can't pass null to the as method, so I kept my statestore name and disabled the caching. I'm testing it now. I assume this does have a performance penalty?

Comment: I first tried it with `Materialized.as("my-store").withCachingDisabled()` but I noticed still messages out of order. Now I disabled the caching of the whole app and that keeps the order but the performance penalty is quite big. Is there something I could do to push the performace up a bit but keep the order guarantee?

Answer (score 0):

> please note that I groupByKey so I would assume that offset is always increasing

In fact offset is increasing per (topic) partition, and messages with the same key (normally) land in the same partition.

So here it looks like you have 2 partitions (at least) and are consuming from both of them.

**Edit once confirmed all messages come from same partition:**

> I add this information to a list

Other idea: could it be that your list is sorted in lexicographical order before you print it?

Comment: Unfortunately I verified that the partition is the same (all messages came from partition 29 in this case)